# Range address for a specific sheet (and not the active sheet)

Tags: excel, range, vba

I want to write a simple function that tells me the column length, giving the first record of the column. Hence, I write something like...

```
Public Function getColumnLen(firstCell As Range) As Long

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range(firstCell.Address).End(xlDown).Row

getColumnLen = lastRow - firstCell.Row + 1
End Function
```

Now I have two worksheets in my project, "A" and "B" and in VBA I call

```
Dim colLen as Long
colLen = getColumnLen(Worksheets("A").Range("A1"))
```

when I want to know the height of data starting on A1. The resulting value of `colLen` depends on whether sheet "A" is active or "B" is active. The thing is that in the `getColumnLen` function, `firstCell` remembers that it is a part of "A" sheet, however scrolling is done on the active sheet. Is there any way to make this give correct results regardless of the active sheet, other than activating `firstCell` in each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're giving it a not-fully-qualified cell address:

```
lastRow = Range(firstCell.Address).End(xlDown).Row
```

Here, `firstCell.Address` returns `$A$1` regardless of what worksheet you specify when you call the function.

- `Worksheets("A").Range("A1").Address`
- `Worksheets("B").Range("A1").Address`
- `Worksheets("Whatever other sheet").Range("A1").Address`

These all return `$A$1`!

Forget about the `Address` property. If you want to know what it does, read VBA help. Just do this instead:

```
lastRow = firstCell.End(xlDown).Row
```

Be advised, however, that this method of finding the last row will fail if you range contains blank cells. This issue has been addressed a gazillion times; just [search this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[vba]+%2Blast+%2Bcell) but be aware that not all of the proposed solutions are equally valid!

Comment: lastrow = firstcell.end(xlup).row

Comment: @scott: um, no. Try it out for yourself!